# Why am I getting Cannot destructure property 'login' of '(0 , _contexts_AuthContext__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useAuth)(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to call the login function which I have in my `AuthContext` on page mount but I get an error that says that my context is undefined which is why I can't destructure the login property.

This is my core App.js component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useAuth } from "./contexts/AuthContext";
import { AuthProvider } from "./contexts/AuthContext";

function App() {
    const { login } = useAuth();

    useEffect(() => {
        login();
    }, []);

    return (
        <AuthProvider>
            <div>Hi</div>
        </AuthProvider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

And my AuthContext file:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import app from "../firebase";

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export const useAuth = () => {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
};

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const login = (email, password) => {
        console.log("login");
        //return app.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    };

    const value = {
        login,
    };

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`useAuth` is consuming the context provided by `AuthProvider`, so it's required to be below `AuthProvider` in the component hierarchy:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Example />
    </AuthProvider>
  )
}
```

```
function Example() {
    const { login } = useAuth();

    useEffect(() => {
        login();
    }, []);

    <div>Hi</div>
}
```

From the [`useContext` docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext):

> The current context value is determined by the value prop of the nearest <MyContext.Provider> above the calling component in the tree.